# When spring applications with gradle multi-module run on intellij's dashboard, it can't load property sources

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

I setup spring boot applications project with gradle multi module project. Each module is just spring boot application. To run all applications, i have to refresh all module using `refresh gradle project` on root project. On the other hand, If i refresh a specific gradle module, other applications which also are submodule cannot load property source.

For a detailed explanation, i want to present sample application:
https://github.com/samplesrepo/sample-demonstrating-boot-cannot-load-propertysource-in-multi-module

And i uploaded a video demonstrating this problem in youtube:
(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5kGu6MhHfmY)

Comment: What IDEA version do you use?

Comment: @y.bedrov 2018.1.1 Ultimate version Build #IU.181-4445.78, And i tried to use EAP version, but also doesn't work.